# what third party repo should be use to install git in Redhat 7 in docker?

Tags: git, docker, redhat, centos7

what third party repo should be use to install package in redhat if i am not subscribe to redhat user.

I am using redhat docker image registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/rhel . this images does't contain any package install .

I have tried all option present in net , may be they are not update .

```
My redhat version is 7.3
64 bit 
and I am not subscribe to redhat . 
So when ever i install any package it say
```

> "This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You
>   can use subscription-manager to register."

And want to install git from third party repository to redhat.
How can be done so?

Comment: ...why do you need a third party repo?

Comment: because redhat ask for subscription and i need only on package to install that is git .If i install git it say error i have update in question .

Comment: have a read at this: https://serverfault.com/a/764902

Comment: I have read this but this doesn't work .

Comment: `wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.10.3.tar.gz`, install

Comment: @TheDarkKnight this is source code not a excutable file .

Comment: mention why -1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See url http://redhat-centos.blogspot.in/2013/06/configuring-centos-base-repo-for-redhat.html
I am adding info because in future the url may not be present .
We can do this by . A running example .
I have used may third party repo for redhat that are EPEL ,rpmforge . They also have good package .
But to do so you can use centos repo instruction to solve this problem .

Go to /etc/yum.repo.d , make a file

CentOS-Base.repo

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# This file uses a new mirrorlist system developed by Lance Davis for CentOS.
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos6
```

and inside this /etc/pki/rpm-gpg

add create file RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7 
and add content from

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

and then see 
yum repolist all 
It will list all the repo , enable centos - base will we active

now run yum install -y git.
git is install.